# How to set value and option in material UI AutoComplete and onChange assign the value to a object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, autocomplete, material-ui

I have a brand object with the field `cat_id`, on page load categories
load into autocomplete select. Now I want to set `category id` as a
value with a category option in autocomplete and also set `cat_id`
from the autocomplete option value `onChange`.

```js
const handleChange = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setBrand({
    ...brand,
    [name]: value,
  });
};

<Autocomplete
  getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.category_name === value.id}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.category_name}
  name="cat_id"
  onInputChange={handleChange}
  options={categories}
  loading={loading}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      label="Category"
      fullWidth
      variant="outlined"
      required
      InputProps={{
        ...params.InputProps,
        endAdornment: (
          <Fragment>
            {" "}
            {loading ? <CircularProgress color="inherit" /> : null}{" "}
            {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
          </Fragment>
        ),
      }}
    />
  )}
/>;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting a while for the help. I manage to solve this but I'm not sure is this a recommended way. I directly set the field value `onChange` and didn't use `handleChange` function.

```
<Autocomplete
  getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.category_name === value.id}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.category_name}
  name="cat_id"
  options={categories}
  loading={loading}
  onChange={(e,option) => setBrand({...brand,cat_id: option.id,})}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      label="Category"
      fullWidth
      variant="outlined"
      required
      InputProps={{
        ...params.InputProps,
        endAdornment: (
          <Fragment>
            {" "}
            {loading ? <CircularProgress color="inherit" /> : null}{" "}
            {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
          </Fragment>
        ),
      }}
    />
  )}
/>;
```